# Should I install 11.10 daily release now or rather wait?

Tags: upgrade, 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a rational reason to wait for the release date to download, install or update to the next version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5257/is-there-a-rational-reason-to-wait-for-the-release-date-to-download-install-or-u)

Should I install ubuntu 11.10 now or is better choice wait to official relase? I know that update should be possible after that but I'm afraid that I will have unnecessary files on my computer from beta version (so, bad windows experiences :) upgrade in windows is always horror). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do either. Both installs are very similar (I haven't had any problems with the beta) and you will just pick up any remaining updates with your next update. The Beta won't leave any unnecessary files.

You will need around 1.5-2hrs for the download and install, so if you have time, you can easily do it now.

Follow these instructions to update now:

- [How do I upgrade to the development release (aka. Ubuntu+1)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12909/how-do-i-upgrade-to-the-development-release-aka-ubuntu1)

Answer (score 0):

wait one more day. release date : October 13th Ubuntu 11.10. Better to install fresh but you can also upgrade using live cd. Avoid to upgrade from online but you can upgrade from CD which is safe.

Comment: Why avoid upgrading online?  What dangers are there?  (I know, this would be better as a question: I'll post it there now.)

Comment: Any links supporting your claim that upgrading online is more dangerous than upgrading from CD?

Answer (score 0):

I would say don't, at least for now. I have upgraded to Oneiric due presence of Gnome3 ppa and ppa-purge didn't help. But nautilus is very unstable and keep closing and data is at risk (when doing move). Compiz also keep crashing. So wait!