# Is upgrading to online more dangerous - or not as good - as a fresh install?

Tags: upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a clean install better than upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading)

I read as an answer to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65509/should-i-install-11-10-daily-release-now-or-rather-wait) that when upgrading to Oneiric, a fresh install is best and that one should avoid updating online.  If this is true, why is it so?  What are the dangers, if any, of updating online.

There is [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5466/is-a-clean-install-better-than-upgrading), written when Maverick was released, that deals somewhat with this question, but it isn't for Oneiric (and things could have changed).  It also doesn't directly deal with what might be bad about installing online.

Besides, as someone who started with Natty, I've never upgraded before.  I suspect there are many like me, who would like current answers to questions about how to upgrade.